# Network error on some devices after build

Tags: java, codenameone

I installed the app after build on different devices (Android) the app opens up fine but when sending network request only one of the device is able to send successfully the others remain unresponsive.
Am using the `Rest.post()` to send that particular request.
Using codename one 6.0 but updated it this morning so I will be using the recent version.
Note: the situation happened before the update. i added a bunch of things while trying to locate the problem.
Here is the code:

```
//...Login button ActionListner
gui_Button_login.addActionListener((ae)->{
        gui_Infinite_Progress.setVisible(true);
        gui_Infinite_Progress.setEnabled(true);
        gui_Button_login.setEnabled(false);
        gui_Text_Field_username.setEnabled(false);
        gui_Text_Field_Password.setEnabled(false);
        if(doLogin()){
            Handle.UserFeed = new UserFeedForm();
            Handle.UserFeed.show();
        }else{
            gui_Button_login.setEnabled(true);
            gui_Text_Field_username.setEnabled(true);
            gui_Text_Field_Password.setEnabled(true);
            gui_Infinite_Progress.setVisible(false);
            gui_Infinite_Progress.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });
//...Do login function
private boolean doLogin(){
    String usr_username = gui_Text_Field_username.getText();
    String usr_password = gui_Text_Field_Password.getText();
    Map<String, Object> signInData = new HashMap<>();
    signInData.put("usr_username", usr_username);
    signInData.put("usr_password", usr_password);
    String signInDataJSON = JSONParser.mapToJson(signInData);

    gui_Span_Label_Debug.setText(gui_Span_Label_Debug.getText() +"\nData:\n"+ signInDataJSON);
    gui_Span_Label_Debug.setText(gui_Span_Label_Debug.getText() +"\nSending...");
    Response<Map> response = Rest.post(Data.API_SIGNIN_URL)
            .jsonContent()
            .body(signInDataJSON)
            .acceptJson()
            .onErrorCodeJSON(err->{
                ToastBar.showErrorMessage(err.getResponseErrorMessage(), Data.MESSAGE_ERROR_TIMEOUT);
                //gui_Span_Label_Debug.setText(gui_Span_Label_Debug.getText() +"\nError:\n"+ err.getResponseErrorMessage());

            }).getAsJsonMap();

    Map<String, Object> responseData = response.getResponseData();
    if(response.getResponseCode() == 0){
        ToastBar.showErrorMessage("Please check your internet!", Data.MESSAGE_ERROR_TIMEOUT);

    }
    gui_Span_Label_Debug.setText(gui_Span_Label_Debug.getText() +"\nResponse Code:\n"+ response.getResponseCode());
    gui_Span_Label_Debug.setText(gui_Span_Label_Debug.getText() +"\nResponse Error Msg:\n"+ response.getResponseErrorMessage());

    if(responseData == null){
        return false;
    }

    if(((String)responseData.get("status")).equalsIgnoreCase("error")){
        ToastBar.showErrorMessage((String)responseData.get("msg"), Data.MESSAGE_ERROR_TIMEOUT);
        return false;
    }

    if(((String)responseData.get("status")).equalsIgnoreCase("success")){
        ToastBar.showMessage((String)responseData.get("msg"), FontImage.MATERIAL_CHECK_CIRCLE, Data.MESSAGE_SUCCESS_TIMEOUT);
        Handle.LoggedInUserData = (Map<String, Object>) responseData.get("data");
        Handle.Authority = (String)Handle.LoggedInUserData.get("jwt");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
//...
```

`Data.API_SIGNIN_URL` is a string containing address accessible via internet e.g. http://94.543.23.4/

Comment: Best of luck on getting a usable answer with what little information you've provided.  I guess it's possible that someone has been in exactly the place you are and will have an idea without more to go on.  To have a better shot at getting an answer, I'd suggest providing some real information as to your code, what your app does, and what back end(s) it is talking to.

Comment: As Steve mentioned, I suggest editing the question with some specifics about the server, addresses and how the connections work.

Comment: i have a codename one built app in which among which  has a login screen that submits request using Rest.post(). to an ip address with a PHP server.
 it is working fine on the emulator and after building it, it works fine on one device but after installing it on other devices the app opens up but clicking the login button does not give any response

Comment: That address isn't accessible in the internet. Try it on the devices that don't work within the browser app.

Comment: That address was an example

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are trying to connect via an IP to a specific machine and it isn't working. This machine is probably visible only within your internal network and the other devices aren't connected to the internal network or choose a route via cell towers.

Comment: That is what am doing but the machine is visible on the internet not the localnetwork. it is working fine on one device but not working on others all android

Comment: If it's an address of a machine within your network its part of a subnet. Try fetching `https://www.codenameone.com` in those devices that "don't work" and see that networking works...

Answer (score 0):

well i added the build hint `android.xpermissions` and set the value to `android.permission.INTERNET\=true,android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE\=true,android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE\=true`.

Its working but seems redundant to me since according to codenameone docs Internet permission is inserted by default. i added the storage just to avert possible similar situation

Comment: That syntax is incorrect and as you mentioned it wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: i see, the problem is most likely with the server address possibly a typo cause am getting erratic behavior. i am verifying all addresses to make sure and will also try your recommendation to fetch  coddename1 site thanks